# You just need to think a little bit to help me find the solution

Tags: arduino

I have rpm, max_rpm and a variable x.

**When rpm aproaches max_rpm -> x tends to 0**

**When rpm aproaches 0 -> x tends to 255**

```
x = (rpm/rpm_max)*255;
arduino.analogWrite(g,(int)x);
```

I have the exact opposite. What can I do? I'm really dumb to figure it out.

Comment: Next time use the correct tag(s)! Arduino is not C!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then maybe this?

```
x = (1 - rpm/rpm_max)*255
```

UPDATE: as mentioned by CandiedOrange - rpm and rpm_max need to be float or double for it to work. Otherwise the value of x would simply switch back and forth between 0 and 255.

Comment: rpm and and rpm_max had better be floats or doubles.  Otherwise x won't 'tend', it'll jump from 0 to 255 all at once due to integer division.  Might want to mention that in the answer.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I thought about that but since he said he had the *exact* opposite I assumed that was already the case and just needed the inversion... but I will do as you suggested anyway... couldn't harm

Comment: What about `x = 255 - 255 * rpm / rpm_max;`? That should work for integers too.